# Javascript: Calculate array of dates from date input

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date

for a personal project i'm scratching my head around this:

I want to take a date input in the future and a number and return an array of dates (in any format) splitted evenly between the present date and the future date.

Ex: Today is 6 nov, i put 1 Dec and n.5: the function(date, num) takes the date differential in days (this part i got) and returns an array of nuum dates (day format let's assume), each at a date-differential/num time. (Vanilla/jquery/lodash/moment, etc... all allowed)

Some brainstorming or pseudo-code more than welcome!

EDIT: i didn't want to share at first because the app is currently broken and it requires moment to run, anyway:

```
calculateReminders = (expirationDate, remindersNum) => {
let rightNow = moment();
let expirationDate = moment(expirationDate);
  if (expirationDate !== null && remindersNum > 0) {
  let differential = expirationDate.diff(rightNow, "days");
    if (differential) {
      let reminderFrequency = differential / remindersNum;
        if (reminderFrequency < 1) {
          Alert.alert(
            "some alert"
          );
          return undefined;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the day differential, but i don't create the subsequent dates array i need.

Comment: Please show the community what you have done to solve the problem yourself. See [ask].

Comment: Yeah you are right, updated the OP, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably gives you what you need. Hope it helps.

```js
const daysDifferential = 20; //This part you got
const n = 5; // Number of dates to return
const increaseOfDays = Math.floor(daysDifferential/n);
const arr = [];

for(let $i = 0; $i < n; $i++) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + $i * increaseOfDays)
  arr.push(d);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That does it. Thank you a lot, Gerard!